# How does HPA*(Hierarchical Pathfinding A*) really work?

Tags: algorithm, path-finding, grid, graph, dijkstra

I'm currently researching for a summary paper on the different variants of A* search algorithm and how they are used in games and I stumbled across the name HPA*. I've heard that it's much more faster than traditional A* but I don't understand it completely. There's hardly any videos or articles written about it so I tried reading a research paper on it and I'm having trouble grasping it. All I can understand is it divides the huge graph in many smaller segments(divide and rule), it creates clusters(subgrids) and precomputes optimal distance between clusters etc..

I would be grateful to any of you if you helped explain it! Thanks in advance.

Comment: [We have lots of past Q&A about HPA*](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=hpa*) - have you taken a look at those discussions and examples?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HAA\* / HPA\* C++ Algorithm / Help](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/151456/haa-hpa-c-algorithm-help)

Comment: @DMGregory I have and the past Q/As are about giving solutions to someone who already knows how HPA* works in detail.

Answer (score 7):

One of the creators of HAA* *(a generalization of HPA*)* wrote a very accessible article explaining how it works on aigamedev.com. Unfortunately that site seems to be dead, but fortunately [archive.org has the article archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20190411040123/http://aigamedev.com/open/article/clearance-based-pathfinding/).

I highly recommend reading it, but to summarize:  HPA* breaks the map into chunks.  In each chunk, you identify the possible entrances/exits to the chunk, and cache the paths/distances between them.  You can then use this to create a graph of the chunks which is much smaller and faster to path-find over than the original map.

[image: Example]

The paths you find with this method are only *near* optimal, but *(after the initial setup cost)* the pathfinding runs much more quickly than plain A*.  You can even group the chunks into larger chunks recursively *(hence the "H" in "HPA", meaning "Hierarchical")* for greater speed benefits.

For more details, see [the original paper](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/%7Emmueller/ps/hpastar.pdf).

Comment: Appreciate your answer. How is the grid really divided into chunks or how is the heuristic evaluated for the hierarchy?